# Oracle - Selecting column values as rows in table 1 based on row value in table 2

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: tables]

I want to select a list of names as output. I want to include the name of **sitegm for all wotranstype's** 
and the name of the **execmgr only if there is a wotranstype of budchg** and the name of the **prodmgr
only for a wotranstype of planning**

So as of now..the result set I need should display

1. Ray
2. Charles

**as there was no transaction type of planning.**

I tried using a case statement with union and to fetch them conditionally as below.

```
  (  
 SELECT   
 CASE WHEN t.wotranstype = 'budchg'  
 THEN w.SITEGM as recipient  
 else NULL  
 end  
 FROM wotrans T, wonotify w  
 WHERE T.PROJNUM = W.PROJNUM  
 )  
 UNION  
 (  
  SELECT   
  CASE WHEN t.wotranstype = 'planning'  
  THEN w.prodmgr as recipient  
  else NULL  
  end  
  FROM wotrans T, wonotify w  
 WHERE T.PROJNUM = W.PROJNUM  
  )  
UNION  
(...
```

Comment: Please show the select you have tried.

Comment: Unrelated but: the parentheses around each select are unnecessary (and useless)

Answer (score 0):

Should just be:

```
select  sitegm
from    wotrans join wonotify using (projnum)
union all
select  execmgr
from    wotrans join wonotify using (projnum)
where   wotranstype = 'budchg'
union all
select  prodmgr
from    wotrans join wonotify using (projnum)
where   wotranstype = 'planning'
```

Comment: If you see closely there are 2 tables mentioned

Comment: @Aravindh see edit with the join added. I thought that the column in the select list and in your case were both from wotrans which would have made the second table of no use. On a side note, you should use the join clause for join conditions, not the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track using UNION. Have you tried placing your criteria in the WHERE section rather than using case, and using UNION ALL:

```
(
SELECT
w.SITEGM as recipient
FROM wotrans T, wonotify w
WHERE T.PROJNUM = W.PROJNUM 
AND t.wotranstype = 'budchg'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 
w.prodmgr as recipient
FROM wotrans T, wonotify w
WHERE T.PROJNUM = W.PROJNUM
AND t.wotranstype = 'planning'
)
UNION ALL
(...
```